# Are loans to be taken from nationalised banks?

Tags: student-visa, austria, loan

Is it necessary to get a loan only from a nationalised bank in order to secure a visa to Austria?

Comment: Why do you think you need a loan to get a visa?

Comment: To show i have enough financing to complete my studies there

Answer (score 1):

[OeAD](https://oead.at/en/to-austria/entry-residence-and-employment/nationals-of-third-countries/), the Austrian Agency for International Cooperation in Education and Research, describes

> Proof of sufficient funds to finance your stay in Austria, e.g. savings or bank deposit, proof of purchase of traveller’s cheques, letter of guarantee of a person living in Austria or an institution domiciled in Austria.

If you need a loan, it would need to be done in advance, so that the entire amount appears in an bank account owned and/or available to you, and one which can be accessed from Austria. There is no separate requirement that a loan be secured from a nationalised bank, or other specific source.

You have to prove sufficient financial means to finance your stay: students up to 24 years of age have to prove that they have at least 491.43 euros per month ; students of 24 years of age or older have to prove that they have at least 889.84 euros per month [as of 2017] – these amounts have to be proved for a maximum of 12 months in advance.

If the costs for accommodation exceed 282,06 euros/month, you will have to prove additional funds.